# How can I init a content with a parameter under .fullScreenCover in IOS14

Tags: swiftui, ios14

.fullScreenCover(isPresented: <#T##Binding#>, content: <#T##() -> View#>)

I need to init a view with a parameter and pass it to .fullScreenCover, I can do it with TesFullScreen.init without problem, but it will error if I init the view with parameter, here is the sample code. Hope someone can help. Thanks

Without parameter is working

```
     .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$showFullScreen, content: TesFullScreen.init)
```

But with parameter is not working

```
     .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$showFullScreen, content: TesFullScreen(closeFlag: self.$showFullScreen, game: 1))
```

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var game : Int = 1
    @State var showFullScreen : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: { self.showFullScreen = true }) {
                    Text("Show Full Screen")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("TextBugs", displayMode: .inline)
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$showFullScreen, content: TesFullScreen.init)
//        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$showFullScreen, content: TesFullScreen(game: 1))
    }
}
```

TesFullScreen

```
struct TesFullScreen: View {
    
    init(game : Int){
        print(game)
    }

    init(){
        print("No parameter work")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Full Screen")
    }
}
```

full coding:
https://github.com/BellRinging/ForBugsFix.git

Comment: You didn't understand me correctly - please create a **minimal** but **reproducible** example - such that I can copy paste into my project, that ideally consist of `struct TesFullScreen: View` **only** and is pasted directly in the question (not as a link to GitHub).

Comment: ic..I reduce the code and you can reproduce by copy and parse. My Xcode version is 12.0

Answer (score 11):

I Got it finally. Need to change it like this

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$showFullScreen){
            TesFullScreen(game: 1)
        }
```